# ROS2 Humble: Package 'ai_assitance' doesn't explicitly install a marker

Tags: gazebo, ros2

I am working on ros2 humble and I am stuck at this error:

```
qrie@qrie-HP-Laptop-15-rb0xx:~/2_ws$ colcon build
Starting >>> ai_assitance
[5.578s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_ros.task.ament_python.build:Package 'ai_assitance' doesn't explicitly install a marker in the package index (colcon-ros currently does it implicitly but that fallback will be removed in the future)
--- stderr: ai_assitance                   
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
---

Finished <<< ai_assitance [4.64s]

Summary: 1 package finished [7.50s]
  1 package had stderr output: ai_assitance
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Error. Is just a warning ⚠️.  In Summary " you can check your package was compiled successfully. The warning is just saying there are newer and better approaches to handle this package dependencies and compilation such as using pip instead setup.py. Warnings are pretty common while building ROS2 Pkgs. But they don't mean your package won't work.

Comment: Good morning thank you for answering but in the next step ,gazebo launches without any robot because it fails to load urdf file

Comment: I suppose it is an issue to set an export of your meshes to the bashrc file or.copy the meshes or model to ~/.gazebo/models folder